# an structure of paired hierarchies of classes

Tags: design-patterns

is there a design pattern who's structure looks like this. B owns a reference to A, and also do some work using A. and further more, each sub class in hierarchy B relay on a sub class in hierarchy A to do its work.
its code looks like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/two-related-hierarchies-of-classes

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parallel inheritance hierarchy, and more commonly viewed as an anti-pattern.

There's some discussion of it on [Ward's Wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParallelInheritanceHierarchies) and at [Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1621) that might be worth reading.

Comment: I understand the reasoning why this is bad, since it can be a maintenance nightmare to maintain both, but what would be a good alternative? Maybe that's beyond the scope of the OP's question, but just identifying the issue seems like half the battle, the other half being a solution :)

Comment: There are some rather vague hints at refactoring solutions on Ward's Wiki (from Ward himself, IIRC).  I might investigate a bit more and try to update.